# Non numeral indeces and the # never counts?

Tags: lua, indexing, lua-table

Given a table with mixed indexes like:

```
table = {
  foo = 'bar'
  [1] = 'foobar'
}
```

My question is about the `#` which gives the last index which is not separate through a gap while iterating through the table.

```
print(#table)
```

will give the output **1**.

```
table = {
  foo = 'bar',
  lol = 'rofl',
  [1] = 'some',
  [2] = 'thing',
  [3] = 'anything',
  [4] = 'else'
}
print(#table)
```

should print **4**

Can I be 100% sure that the `#` will never be distracted by non-numeral indexes?
Are those indexes really unregarded at every time?

Comment: Although it's easy to understand what you mean, it's better to make your example code compilable. Your table constructor like `4 = else` is obviously illegal.

Comment: Okay, done. Didn't noticed while typing.

Comment: Allow me to eidt your code, it's more than `else` beging a keyword. `[4] = 'else'` looks a little less clear and unlike the more common syntax sugar, but it's legal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can count on that (in lua 5.1).

From the lua [reference manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.5.5):

> The length operator is denoted by the unary operator #. The length of
>   a string is its number of bytes (that is, the usual meaning of string
>   length when each character is one byte).
>
> The length of a table t is defined to be any integer index n such that
>   t[n] is not nil and t[n+1] is nil; moreover, if t[1] is nil, n can be
>   zero. For a regular array, with non-nil values from 1 to a given n,
>   its length is exactly that n, the index of its last value. If the
>   array has "holes" (that is, nil values between other non-nil values),
>   then #t can be any of the indices that directly precedes a nil value
>   (that is, it may consider any such nil value as the end of the array).

lua 5.2 allows for the `__len` metamethod to operate on tables and that means `#` can do other things. See @kikito's answer for some examples.

Answer (score 2):

Etan answer is correct, but not complete.

In Lua, if a table's metatable has a `__len` function, it will control what the `#` operator spits out. One can define it so that it takes into account the non-array keys.

```
local mt = {__len = function(tbl)
  local len = 0
  for _ in pairs(tbl) do len = len + 1 end
  return len
end}
```

This demonstrates the thing:

```
local t = {1,2,3,4,foo='bar',baz='qux'}

print(#t) -- 4
setmetatable(t, mt)
print(#t) -- 6
```

If you *really* want to make sure that you get the "proper" array-like length, you must use `rawlen` instead:

```
print(rawlen(t)) -- 4, even with the metatable set
```

Edit: Note that `__len` does not work as I mention on Lua 5.1

Comment: And again, thank you for the guide but it doesn't fit the question.

Comment: The [Lua 5.1 reference manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.8) always said, that the `__len` metamethod does not work on tables (or strings) ...

Comment: @Sempie: In the question you ask "Can I be 100% sure that the # will *never* be distracted by non-numeral indexes?". The answer to that "absolute never" is no (metamethods can change it). I think it is pertinent.

Comment: Indeed, lua 5.2 changes the behaviour of `#` a bit in a way that is relevant here.

Comment: Good point about the default # (rawlen) being able to be overridden by __len. One note about rawlen, though: It applies only to tables with a sequence. Array is an implementation detail. The standard implementation can have an array part even when the table doesn't have a sequence.

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to iterate through entries and count them. Iterate with ipair through the item and increment counter then return result.

```
function tablelength(T)
 local count = 0 for _ in pairs(T) do
    count = count + 1 end
 return count 
end
```

The # operator only work for hash table type.

See: [How to get number of entries in a Lua table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705793/how-to-get-number-of-entries-in-a-lua-table)

Comment: I don't want to get the lenght of the table, that's not the question here. But beside this, what is a ash table? Even the russian friends from google don't know.

Comment: Sorry i misunderstood your question. I was speaking of hash array.. Typo. But you can use this method to get the last index.

Comment: `#` explicitly does *not* work for tables with non-numeric indices.

Comment: It does not work für the fields with non-numeric indices, as argued it counts the numeric indeces from lowest to n or gap.