# Get Lua table size in C

Tags: c, lua, lua-table, lua-api, lua-5.1

How can I get a size of a Lua table in C?

```c
static int lstage_build_polling_table (lua_State * L) {
    lua_settop(L, 1);
    luaL_checktype(L, 1, LUA_TTABLE);
    lua_objlen(L,1);
    int len = lua_tointeger(L,1);
    printf("%d\n",len);
    ...
}
```

My Lua Code:

```lua
local stages = {}
stages[1] = stage1
stages[2] = stage2
stages[3] = stage3

lstage.buildpollingtable(stages)
```

It´s printing 0 always. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "Size of a table" is a strange term to use. You are getting the length of the sequence in a table (possibly 0), if the table has a sequence as defined in the manual, otherwise indeterminate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`lua_objlen` returns the length of the object, it doesn't push anything on the stack.

Even if it did push something on the stack your `lua_tointeger` call is using the index of the table and not whatever `lua_objlen` would have pushed on the stack (if it pushed anything in the first place, which it doesn't).

You want `size_t len = lua_objlen(L,1);` for lua 5.1.

Or `size_t len = lua_rawlen(L,1);` for lua 5.2.

Comment: Actually, the type is `size_t`. Also, since Lua 5.2 the name is `lua_rawlen`: http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#lua_rawlen

Comment: Note: these methods will only work for "lists", i.e. lua tables with [1..] consecutive indices.  Details discussed on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705793/how-to-get-number-of-entries-in-a-lua-table

Answer (score 4):

In the code you gave, just replace `lua_objlen(L,1)` with `lua_len(L,1)`.

`lua_objlen` and `lua_rawlen` return the length and do not leave it on the stack.

`lua_len` returns nothing and leaves the  length on the stack; it also respect metamethods.

Comment: Note: these methods will only work for "lists", i.e. lua tables with [1..] consecutive indices.  Details discussed on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705793/how-to-get-number-of-entries-in-a-lua-table