# How to get returned table from Lua function in C++?

Tags: c++, lua, lua-table

I'm trying to figure out how to get the returned table from the Lua function in C++.

My code:

```
if (lua_pcall(L, 0, 1, 0)) {
        std::cout << "ERROR : " << lua_tostring(L, -1) << std::endl;
}
vector<float> vec;

if (lua_istable(L, -1) { 

    //how to copy table to vec?
}
```

How can I copy the returned table to vector if the table size is unknown? Thanks!

Comment: If the question is just about getting the size of the table, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26643285/get-lua-table-size-in-c). Or are you asking for generating a std::vector from the table ?

Comment: here's another answer that might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6142700/847349

Comment: @DmitryLedentsov Do you mind posting an actual example of copying returned table to float vector using `lua_next`? I'd appreciate it.

Comment: you can simply use [luastackcrawler](https://github.com/d-led/luastackcrawler) or any other comparable library. Here's a [generic table crawler](https://github.com/d-led/luastackcrawler/blob/f775ba95878b0ba8b27135ee651028357404ea78/luatablestack/luatablecrawler.cpp), which you could try to understand to write your special simple use case. I won't be able to write an example now

Comment: have you tried to understand the Lua book [PiL](https://www.lua.org/pil/25.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found out how to do it using `lua_next`.

```
lua_getglobal(L, name);

if (lua_pcall(L, 0, 1, 0)) {
        std::cout << "ERROR : " << lua_tostring(L, -1) << std::endl;
}
vector<float> vec;

if (lua_istable(L, -1) { 

   lua_pushvalue(L, -1);
   lua_pushnil(L);

   while (lua_next(L, -2))
   {

        if (lua_isnumber(L, -1))
        {
            vec.push_back(lua_tonumber(L, -1));
        }
        lua_pop(L, 1);
    }
    lua_pop(L, 1);
}
```