# Trying to understand example in book "Programming in Lua"

Tags: lua

Trying to understand exercise 5.1 in Programming in Lua, fourth edition

The code is included, but I don't understand what's going on

```
sunday = "monday" ; monday = "sunday"
print("After first line ", sunday, monday)
t = {sunday = "monday", [sunday] = monday}
print("Printing #t", #t)
for k = 1 , #t do
  print(k, t[k])
end
print("After printing ipairs")
print(t.sunday, t[sunday], t[t.sunday])
```

The results I'm getting are as follows:-

*After first line   monday  sunday

Printing #t 0

After printing ipairs

monday  sunday  sunday*

It's basically line 3 that is confusing me. Why are the number of elements in t zero ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The length of a table t is defined to be any integer index n such that t[n] is not nil and t[n+1] is nil; moreover, if t[1](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.5.5) is nil, n can be zero. For a regular array, with non-nil values from 1 to a given n, its length is exactly that n, the index of its last value. If the array has "holes" (that is, nil values between other non-nil values), then #t can be any of the indices that directly precedes a nil value (that is, it may consider any such nil value as the end of the array).

Taken from the [Lua 5.1 Manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.5.5)

To correctly obtain the length of a table using the # operator, the table must be indexed with integers and be sequential. For example: `t = {[1] = "monday", [2] = monday}`

In your case, the keys of your table are strings. There are methods to loop through non-sequential tables, one of these methods is with the function `pairs`.

```
t = {sunday = "monday", [sunday] = monday}
for k, v in pairs(t) do
  print(k, v)
end
```

Likewise, to obtain the length of a non-sequential table, you could loop through the table and count the number of elements. [How to get number of entries in a Lua table?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2705804/8701297)

Comment: Thank you Lewis for taking the time to clear up (?) my problem.